# Azure SQL users and Schemas

Tags: sql, azure, schema

I have an Azure SQL database and an Access frontend combination that is working great but then got asked to provide a training version. I though the best route was to create a new schema and create duplicate tables. I've been able to create the schema, a new login/user and copy the tables across. The original tables in 'dbo' and the new tables in schema 'trn'. The plan was to remove the schema specifications from my Access queries and rely on the logins ('user' for schema 'dbo' and 'trainee' for schema 'trn') to access the tables in the appropriate schema. My problem is my new login/user 'trainee' queries don't get directed to the 'trn' schema but to the original 'dbo' schema. I've searched the internet for answers and tried all sorts of permission changes, grants and revokes etc. to no avail. I'm clearly missing something, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

dbo is the default schema if you don't do anything about it. Have you set the default schema for the user correctly?

Also if you are rellying on view and stored procedures you will most likely run into all sorts of nasty "exeecuted as" problems.

I'd recommend this link for reading up on how top set the default schema.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql

Cheers

Comment: Thank you @user1694674. I had set the default schema but did so again just to be sure. I've spent the afternoon working on this and to be fair to Azure, the problem isn't with the Server. From my research and testing I've found the problem lies in my Access front-end. I was trying to change the ODBC connect string from one user-login to another on-the-fly but Access won't let me (I think as soon as the first connection is made to the server the ODBC link is maintained and the uid and pwd can't be changed). I'll keep looking for a solution and post it if I find it.